Error al aplicar recaptcha V3 en subdirectorios
he implementado recaptcha v3 en un formulario de un sitio principal, dominio base miweb.com. y funciona correctamente.
Al intentar implementarlo en un formulario ubicado en un subdirectorio del mismo sitio ej: miweb.com/admin en el formulario aparece:

Al cambiar las claves con una de recaptcha v2, éste funciona en el subdirectorio; pero usando una de tipo v3 ocurre el error.
La config de las llaves solo tiene asociado el dominio base, se asume que toma cualquier subdominio o ruta derivada del mismo.
¿ Cómo se puede solventar esto ? ¿ se puede aplicar a subdirectorios ?

Y las claves son diferentes? Por ejemplo, las claves de V3 no funcionan para V2, y las V2 no funcionan con Invisible reCaptcha. Las claves no son intercambiables. Es código puro, Wordpress, Plugins??
